# Where is the k8s yaml file generally placed?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it professional in this position of the server?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFIXb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there and welcome to StackOverflow. This question is probably going to be closed soon for being unclear. Kubernetes is driven by an API so where you put the files is up to you, as long as you upload them into the API, usually via `kubectl apply`. It's hard to be more specific than that given how vague your question is.